# "Former and Latter for upcoming list: "following latter" or "latter following", or just "latter"?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

According to [this page](http://editingandwritingservices.com/former-latter/), they use former and latter in the following way:

> “I enjoy read­ing Entrepreneur and Inc, but pre­fer the lat­ter over
>   the former.”

The issue I'm having is how to structure a sentence with the list upcomming, such as if I rewrote their quote:

> Although I prefer the **following latter** over the **following former**, I
>   enjoy reading both the Entrepreneur and Inc.

How should I phrase that part bolded above?  (Also, it may seem constrained, but in my actual use the two parts are more distant from each other.)

Comment: Why would you want to confuse your audience like that? The *position in an as-yet-unspecified list* of your personal preference can't be so important that you have to specify it  before the audience/reader even knows what you're talking about.

Comment: Although I prefer Entrepreneur over Inc, I enjoy reading both.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's for a code snippet in an email, and I'd like to talk about the changes, then quote the before/after.  I used a contrived example just for simplicity and to highlight the question.

Comment: It seems like you have handcuffed yourself to "turning a phrase" that does not serve your purposes well. My advice: Walk away from the whole former/latter debate and say it another way :)

Comment: George Orwell ought to be spinning in his grave.

Comment: It's easy to say something differently; I came here to see if there was a better way to say what I was trying to say.  I don't understand the point of this "advice" and sass in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the formulas you offered seemed remotely succinct :)

In introducing your two code snippets, this is the way I would phrase it:

"I've offered two solutions. I like them both, but I like the second one better."

Comment: I like them both, but the first was more succinct! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the identity of your preference hidden until the end like this:

> Although I prefer the first of the following two magazines, I enjoy
>   reading them both: Entrepreneur and INC.

or like this

> Although I prefer the first of the following magazines over the 
>   second, I enjoy reading them both: Entrepreneur and INC.

Answer (score -1):

It's certainly possible to structure a sentence like the one you've written, but you would leave off the "following" qualifier:

> Although I prefer the **latter** over the **former**, I enjoy reading both the Entrepreneur and Inc.

Latter and former refer to two-element lists by definition, and in this case the reader is being forewarned that such a list is coming (and that you prefer the second item to the first). Note that this is a fairly unusual construction that comes off as overly formal or antiquated, and would not be used in most cases.  But it would be correct, and would be recognized and correctly interpreted by most readers.